# This code is not working properly and it doesn't make any sense why it isn't to me. Does anyone have a guess what the problem might be?

Tags: c++, random

[This](https://repl.it/@redsox2/Hangman#main.cpp) is the link to the hangman game in C++ I am making. It works perfectly fine on [repl](https://repl.it/%7E), but it doesn't work when I try to build and run it. It shoes letters have been guessed at the very start of the game, when which, obviously you haven't guessed any. The letters are also rather random having nothing to do with the game or anything, at least I think. Can someone else at least run this on their computer and see if it is just me? Thanks! It starts with:

```
WELCOME TO HANGMAN!!


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Here are the rules:
* you must enter one letter
* that letter cannot be a symbol
* you have ten guesses
* correct guesses won't count against you
* you cannot guess the same letter twice
* and finally, if you need to give up enter any numeral



You have 10 incorrect guesses left
The word so far is

_ _ _ _ _


You have guessed: A, B, I, J, K, Q, R, T,
What is your guess?
```

This is what is does give when first opened, however, I want it to show that you haven't guessed anything yet, because you haven't.

```cpp
cout << "You have " << guesses << " incorrect guesses left" << endl;
    cout << "The word so far is\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
      if (i == word.length() - 1)
      {
        cout << guessedWord[i] << endl;
      }
      else
      {
        cout << guessedWord[i] << " ";
      }
    }
    cout << "\n\nYou have guessed: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < guessed.size(); ++i)
    {
      if (guessed[i])
      {
        cout << static_cast<char>(i + 'A') << ", ";
      }
    }
    cout << "\nWhat is your guess?" << endl;
    cin >> myGuess;
    istringstream myGuess2(myGuess);
    char guess = toupper(myGuess2.peek());
    if (isalpha(guess) == false)
    {
      if (isdigit(guess) == true)
      {
        break;
      }
      else
      {
        cout << "That is not a letter, please try again" << endl;
        continue;
      }
    }
    else if (guessed[guess - 'A'])
    {
      cout << "You have already guessed this." << endl;
      continue;
    }
```

This is what that part of it looks like, if none of the conditions by which you want to give up (if you enter a number) or if you do not enter an actual alphabetical character, then it goes on to take the ascii value of you guess, subtract the ascii value of 'A' to get the place of the letter in the array of bools, then it sets that letter's value to true. After it just checks if your guess is correct and everything, but that works fine for now.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Please copy and paste your raw source code directly into the question body. Also, please give input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: What do you mean 'raw source code'?

Comment: Please post your code (into the question) as text.  Firewalls are preventing me from following your link.

Comment: The relevant code to reproduce the problem has to be part of your question and not an external link. The questions ask here should not only help the one asking the question but any future reader. As of that, it is required, that the questions contain all relevant information without the need to rely on an external link that could be become unreachable anytime.

Comment: Ok, but it is a lot of code (for my standards at least). I am not sure what part of the code would be reproducible either.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Divide and conquer. Try to make a small program that has the same misbehaviour as the whole program. Post the small program assuming making the small program didn't remove enough of the noise the bug's hiding in for you to spot the problem and fix it. Use [mre] for inspiration.

Comment: Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session.  For example, indicate which statement is failing, the actual values of variables and the expected values of variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still do not include all relevant code in your question.

> It shoes letters have been guessed at the very start of the game, when which, obviously you haven't guessed any.

The problem is at this point of your code:

```
array<bool, 26> guessed;
```

This does not set the elements of the `array` to `false`, and they have an indeterminate value.

If you want that they are `false` you need to write:

```
array<bool, 26> guessed{};
```

To avoid such problems, you can go with AAA Style (Almost Always Auto), and define your variables that way:

```
auto guessed = array<bool, 26>();
```